# Google Drive API 400 Bad Request on chunked file upload

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Following strictly googles tutorial([google drive resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable)).
The initial POST request is a success. With the request I send some metadata along(the files title) and I get a response with the `Location` header including the `upload_id` parameter. I save that uri and start my chunked upload process.

I'm going to post the request from Chrome's developer tools network tab, this should reveal anything that I have possibly missed.

```
Remote Address:xxx.xxx.xx.x:443
Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEn...
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:400 Bad Request

Request Headers
:host:www.googleapis.com
:method:PUT
:path:/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEn...
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*//*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,et;q=0.6,ja;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2,de;q=0.2
authorization:Bearer ya29...
cache-control:no-cache
content-length:204800
content-range:bytes 0-204799/9623941
content-type:application/x-msdownload
origin:http://localhost:8080
pragma:no-cache
referer:http://localhost:8080/index.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
x-client-data:CI62yQEIprbJAQiptskBCMS2yQEInobKAQi4iMoBCPGIygE=

Query String Parameters
uploadType:resumable
upload_id:AEn...

Response Headers
access-control-allow-origin:http://localhost:8080
access-control-expose-headers:Content-Length, Content-Type, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=0.01
content-length:193
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:Sun, 28 Sep 2014 17:50:48 GMT
server:UploadServer ("Built on Sep 18 2014 17:00:06 (1411084806)")
status:400 Bad Request
vary:Origin
version:HTTP/1.1
```

Ignore the second slash in the accept header.

This is the response I get after I start the first chunk upload. Everything seems to be correct according to googles reference, but it's not working.

I'm not using googles client.js library. Using plain old `XMLhttpRequest()`.

Comment: can you post the original POST and response. Are you sure about the mime type "application/x-msdownload"?

Comment: @pinoyyid It seems there was a problem on googles side yesterday. Fired up my application and it works like a charm, getting the proper response etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fine on my side. My request was correct, but there seemed to be a problem with googles services yesterday(28.09.2014). Everything works fine now.